# sharepoint 2013 task not showing open this task button

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, task, sharepoint-2013, workflow

I've been trying to find answers to this situation in other threads/sites, with no success.

Just starting with SharePoint 2013 and using SPD, I created a very basic list with a text field and a date. If I create and assign a SharePoint 2010 workflow, and have the following as a workflow step:

```
Log STARTED to the workflow history list
then Start Approval process on Current Item with <my email>
then Log FINISHED to the workflow history list
```

An email is sent to me with a button Open this Task in Outlook's ribbon - this is what I want, so far so good... FYI, all options to start approval process are default, and workflow is expected to pause until task is approved/rejected.

If I delete the 2010 workflow and create/assign a 2013 workflow with these steps:

```
Log START to the workflow history list
then Assign a task to <my email> (Task outcome to Variable:Outcome| Task ID to Variable:TaskID)

if Variable:Outcome equals Approved
   Log APPROVED to the workflow history list
Else
   Log REJECTED to the workflow history list

Go to End of Workflow
```

I receive an email without a Open this task button, and users need to open the task that was created, edit it and then click on [Approve]. Too many additional steps.

Both workflows (2010/2013) are set to start automatically on any changes.

Apologies, can't copy/paste screenshots here, since I'm posting from my personal laptop. Any help is really appreciated here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have Task outcome as the last column in the column order to get the outcome as buttons

To do that, you need to goto

> List settings-> click on the content type name(workflow task 2013) ->
>   click on column order -> Make the task outcome as last column and
>   click ok

[image]

Now if you refresh your task edit page, you should be able to see the Approve/Reject as buttons